# mkfs.ext4: invalid blocks offset=X on device device.img

Tags: filesystems, partition, ext4

My goal is to create a regular file and within it make a partition and file systems (literally a virtual hard drive) and finally mount it, so I did:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=imagem-zero.img count=20480000
```

To create the file with aprox 20Gb. Then I've partitioned with `cfdisk`, after that the status of the file was:

```
$ gdisk -l imagem-zero.img

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk imagem-zero.img: 40960000 sectors, 19.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 544A9633-7FA3-4BE8-BEE7-612C151A4504
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 2048, last usable sector is 40959966
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 0 sectors (0 bytes)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048        16779263   8.0 GiB     8304  
   2        16779264        40959966   11.5 GiB    8302
```

Now, I want to make the file system `ext4` in both these two partitions but I'm failing with the error message in the title of the question:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 imagem-zero.img offset=$((2048*512))
mke2fs 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
mkfs.ext4: invalid blocks 'offset=1048576' on device 'imagem-zero.img'

$ sudo mkfs.ext4 imagem-zero.img offset=$((2048))
mke2fs 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
mkfs.ext4: invalid blocks 'offset=2048' on device 'imagem-zero.img'
```

My question is, how to find the correct offset to make the file system on both of the partitions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write to an .img file with two different partitions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208398/how-to-write-to-an-img-file-with-two-different-partitions)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/367196/linux-how-to-format-multiple-file-systems-within-one-file?newreg=754bef1f5f6446e18cb816d0edf750fd

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa SuperUser does not have (almost) anything to do with us.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa It is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 2):

### You have just forgotten to use the `-E` switch!

**In addition, I have suggestion not to use `sudo`, when not necessary.**

1. Create a zeroed file, no need for `sudo` here:

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=image-zero.dd count=20480000 status=progress
   ```
2. Partition the zeroed image with `cfdisk` as you like, no need for `sudo` here:

   ```
   cfdisk image-zero.dd
   ```
3. Create the file system on the partition(s) using, no need for `sudo` here:

   ```
   mkfs.ext4 image-zero.dd -E offset=$(( 512 * 2048 ))
   ```
4. Create some mount point directory:

   ```
   mkdir mnttest
   ```
5. Mount the image with, notice there is need for `sudo` here:

   ```
   sudo mount -t ext4 -o offset=$(( 512 * 2048 )) image-zero.dd ./mnttest
   ```

**Tested on Linux Mint 19.**

---

### How to find proper offsets

Your image has:

- Logical sector size: 512 bytes
- Start sector of the first partition: 2048
- Start sector of the second partition: 16779264

**Calculation:**

Multiply the Logical sector size with the Start sector of a partition and let's do the math with your shell.

**Results:**

- 1st partition: `offset=$(( 512 * 2048 ))`
- 2nd partition: `offset=$(( 512 * 16779264 ))`

Comment: it worked for `mkfs.ext4` but not for mouting: `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.`

Comment: @Fabiotk try re-create the image and re-try the steps, as of this moment I am kind of unsure what went wrong, please do it exactly as I say in this answer, just delete the old image first, ok..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you could create the file system with the `offset=` option, how would you use it?

The man page says

> -E extended-options
>
> Set extended options for the filesystem.  Extended options are comma separated, and may take an argument using the equals ('=') sign.
>
> offset=offset
>
> Create the filesystem at an offset from the beginning of the device or file.  This can be useful when creating disk images for virtual machines.

So the correct syntax would be

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 imagem-zero.img -E offset=$((2048))
```

This would allow you to create the file system, but you probably also want to write some files. So it's better to use a loop device.

```
losetup -P -f imagem-zero.img
```

This will give you `/dev/loopX` and partitions `/dev/loopXp0`,`/dev/loopXp1`. You can use `mkfs` on these partitions, mount them and write files to these partitions. After unmounting the partitions, do

```
losetup -d /dev/loopX
```

Comment: The use of loop device is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @Vlastimil Even if it is not necessary, a loop device makes the process much easier.